# iPhone client not registering for push?

Tags: iphone, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I "think" my app is not registering for push notifications.

It should be as simple as adding the code to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and then the when tested the app alert for push notifications should (but does not in my case) pop up.

my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

return YES;
}
```

This is an iPad app.  It is running without push on my real device so I assume the provisioning is correct.

Any ideas?  I do not get the push  Don't allow/ok pop up.

[image: push]

Answer (score 1):

Do u have this code in your delegate?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 

    NSString *str = [NSString 
        stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(str);

}
```

You should get the device token generated and put it in your server where you want to push your notification..

If let say you have everything right on the iphone part, the problem may lies on your server code where you push your notification..

Take a look at this tutorial about push notification :
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Comment: Yes I do.  On a side note do I need to send the device token to my server if so how? and where?

Comment: Yes .. u need to send the device token to the server.. Once you get the token from the above method, send the token over the network to your server. For the server side example/codes.. you can try to go to the link above..

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the delegate methods and set up the certificates on your server.  Here is some code for the objc side:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    NSString *token = [[devToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@""] forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"] 
                                                     message:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
}
```

- A good tutorial about setting up the server and Dev Center certs - [How to renew your Apple Push Notification Push SSL Certificate](http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/06/05/how-to-renew-your-apple-push-notification-push-ssl-certificate/)
- [How to build an Apple Push Notification provider server (tutorial)](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have the other part of the code also. I was under the impression that the pop up would happen weather the server stuff was done yet or not?

I got it working.  I had to get a new provisioning file.  Delete the old one. The go into the app folder. View contents of the project file. Open with text editor the file with the provisioning key in it and swap the key (two spots) out with the new key code.

Now it works.  Thanks for the help.